# Notifee new foreground service is added for each notification shown

Tags: android, react-native

The notification is correctly shown on button press and cleared when selecting "Stop" button on the notification. However, every time I show a notification, new `onForegroundEvent` is registered, so now it's triggered more than once. Why is that? For example, if I show and clear the notification and show and try to clear it again, `onForegroundEvent` is called twice.

According to [documentation](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/events#foreground-events), `onForegroundEvent` returns `unsubscribe()` method, but I don't know how this is useful, because I want to unsubscribe when notification action is selected which would be handled within that method.

I register foreground service once outside of React component like this:

```
notifee.registerForegroundService((notification) => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
      if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction) {
        switch (detail.pressAction.id) {
          case 'pause':
            console.log('Paused...');
            break;
          case 'resume':
            console.log('Resumed...');
            break;
          case 'stop':
            console.log('Stopped...');
            notifee.stopForegroundService();
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I define a method inside a React component to display a notification on button press. Relevant code looks like this:

```
const onDisplayNotification = async () => {
  await notifee.requestPermission();

  notifee.displayNotification({
    id: 'task-stream',
    title: 'Foreground Service Notification',
    body: 'Press the Quick Action to stop the service',
    android: {
      channelId: 'default',
      showChronometer: true,
      asForegroundService: true,
      colorized: true,
      color: AndroidColor.BLUE,
      actions: [
        {
          title: 'Pause',
          pressAction: {
            id: 'pause'
          }
        },
        {
          title: 'Stop',
          pressAction: {
            id: 'stop',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

So, how do I remove `onForegroundEvent` listener after the foreground service is stopped?